# MX record not detected by the outer world

Tags: domain-name-system, email, windows-server-2008-r2

we have setup our web server with Active directory in windows 2008 R2 environment. We are facing very strange problem that MX record which we have already created in our DNS not detected by anyone outside the organization. Due to all this we are facing the problem in mailing services.

Regards
Sandeep Goel

Answer (score 1):

HI,
Where is your domain's DNS hosted?
If you do a NSlookup on your domain external to your network where does it say your Name servers and MX records Point to?
When did you last make changes to your MX records?

**INITIAL VIEW**

It sounds like you have set your MX records internally on your server, we need to confirm your domain name is registered, is connected to a global name server and you have set your MX record correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that your DNS is in charge of the Domain.
You can validate this by checking the listed nameserver of domain at the nic or registrar

Comment: Domain is pointed to same servers and the DNS is controlled by active directory in windows 2008 R2 environment. MX record and supported A record is also there. but when we query through our local system or web toll then MX is not detected.